# How to impersonate a user CRM 2011 user?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011, impersonation

**Server A:**

1. I am having CRM (2011) portal deployed on a server.
2. There is one WCF service "Discovery.svc" which got installed and configured during installation of CRM2011.

**Server B:**

1. My development machine is in another domain than the CRM portal.
2. I am trying to write an ASP.NET website which expects to call "Discovery.svc" of CRM portal within the context of CRM user.
   For that, I have written following in web.config:

> ```
> <identity impersonate="true" password="password" userName="domainname\username"/>
> ```

Currently I am running the website in the development environment only, and not in IIS (because its having IIS 5.1, so I thought to run it within Visual Studio only)

Doing this is giving me following error message:

"Could not create Windows user token from the credential specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

but I know my credentials are correct.

Can anyone guide me what could be wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you adding the domain name to your user credentials? Declare the user credentials to use domain\username.

Comment: yes, I have set userName = "domainname\username".. see <identity> tag in the question.